# Can XSD defaults be dynamic?

Tags: xml, xsd, default

Suppose I use XSD to define a `<collection>` which contains 1-5 `<thing>` elements:

```
<xs:element name="collection">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="thing" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="5">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <!-- can I make this attribute's default increment / change? -->
                    <xs:attribute name="identifier" default="no1" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Each `<thing>` element has an `@identifier` attribute. I want to give the `@identifier` attribute a default value, but I want that value to be different for each `<thing>` element - and ideally I'd prefer if the default varied by position in the document:

```
<collection>
    <thing identifier="no1" />
    <thing identifier="no2" />
    <thing /><!-- implicit / default identifier of "no3" -->
</collection>
```

Can this kind of definition/behavior be achieved using XSD?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: no.

You're way outside the scope of what a schema is for; use XSLT.